# Passing flags to a program in a bash script

Tags: bash, flags

**Background**

I have a program `prog` that takes input from stdin and does something to it. It also takes a flag `-f FILE` to find a datafile used during operation.

I wish to create a bash script to act as a wrapper around this program so that this flag need not be used. So I wrote the following script `progwrap.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

/path/to/prog -f /path/to/data
```

which does the trick for basic functionality, so that I can do something like

```
$ cat somedata.txt | progwrap.sh
```

and get what I want.

**Goal**

Now, it turns out that `prog` also takes some other flags of the form `-h`, `-u`, etc... I want to be able to pass these to `progwrap.sh` so that they are in turned passed to `prog`. So I amended `progwrap.sh` as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

/path/to/prog -f /path/to/data "$@"
```

allowing it to take arguments and supposedly feeding them to `prog` within the script.

**Problem**

However this somehow doesn't work, in that:

```
$ cat somedata.txt | progwrap.sh -h
```

produces the exact same output as

```
$ cat somedata.txt | progwrap.sh
```

which is not the correct behaviour (i.e. the output should come out in a different format as a result of the -h flag being passed to progwrap.sh).

In fact, feeding `progwrap` nonsense arguments for which `prog` has no support, and which usually cause `prog` to throw an error, does nothing. I conclude that the arguments passed to `progwrap.sh` are ignored by the call to `prog` within the script.

**Question**

What am I doing wrong? How can I pass flags to `progwrap.sh` so that these flags are then passed to `prog` within my script?

Comment: No, your script is fine.

Comment: melpomene: why is the program no using the said flags, then?

Comment: Maybe you're editing the wrong script file. Or the program is broken and ignores everything after `-f`. Hard to tell.

Comment: Righto, it turns out you are correct and the fault lie with the program ignoring everything after -f FILE, which is undocumented.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user melpomene for helping. It turns out the above script is fine for passing flags, and the fault lie with `prog` ignoring all flags after `-f File`. The script works fine when modified to:

```
#!/bin/bash

/path/to/prog "$@" -f /path/to/data
```

Thanks!

PS. In my defence this flag behaviour was not documented by the designers of `prog`.

Comment: In `prog`'s defense, that behavior is actually quite standard: first come all options, then all other arguments. One of the benefits of this approach is, if you need an actual argument that happens to start with `--`, you can use the special `--` option to indicate "end of options". (For example, `grep -- --foo bar.sh` will search the file `bar.sh` for lines containing the string `--foo`.)